# azure webapps で、令和元年ではなく令和1年と表示させる設定

Tags: c#, .net, azure

AzureのWebappsで公開しているシステムで和暦対応に、GetEraメソッドを使用しています。
ここで、5月の改元によって、元号が「令和元年」と表示されています。
windows上では、[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Calendars\Japanese]  で InitialEraYear レジストリ キーの設定により、元年/1年の変更が可能ですが、Azureのwebapps上で同様の設定方法の情報がみつかりません。
ご存知の方がいらっしゃったらご教示ください。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

使用言語が指定されていませんが、C#などの.NET環境でしょうか？

[Handling a new era in the Japanese calendar in .NET](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/handling-a-new-era-in-the-japanese-calendar-in-net/#user-content-the-first-year-of-an-era)で説明されていますが構成ファイルに次のように記述することで制御できないでしょうか？

```
<AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Globalization.FormatJapaneseFirstYearAsANumber=true" />
```

Comment: asp.net c# でしたので、いただいた情報をもとに、web.configのappSettingsに以下の設定を追加する事で対応できました。ありがとうございました。`<add key="AppContext.SetSwitch:Switch.System.Globalization.FormatJapaneseFirstYearAsANumber" value="true" />`

Comment: @sakaguchi 解決したようでしたら回答横にある✓をクリックして承認してください。